# Problem with automount and exfat fstype

Tags: automount, exfat

I need some help to configure automount with exfat filesystem (no problem with ext4 for example).

```
$ sudo automount -f -v
$ ls /home/user/automount
```

Automount return this error.

```
mounted direct on /home/user/automount with timeout 120, freq 30 seconds
attempting to mount entry /home/user/automount
>> /sbin/mount.exfat: invalid option -- 's'
>> Usage: /sbin/mount.exfat [-d] [-o options] [-V] <device> <dir>
>> FUSE exfat 1.1.0
failed to mount /home/user/automount
```

Configuration files.

```
$ cat /etc/auto.master.d/removal.autofs 
/- /etc/auto.removal uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=120,--ghost

$ cat /etc/auto.removal 
/home/user/automount -fstype=exfat UUID=54E8-C318
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with autofs version 5.1.1.

```
$ wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/autofs/autofs_5.1.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i autofs_5.1.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```